# column of an array as a vector argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass as a vector argument a column of an array, but I do not know how to do it. I am using "vector" library. I am going to post an example for clarify what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//function for get the sum of all the elements of a vector H
double suma(vector<double> H) {
    double Sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < H.size(); i++) {
        Sum += H[i];
    }
    return Sum;
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<double> > phi;
    phi.resize(10, vector<double> (2,1.0));
    cout << suma(phi[][1]) << endl;
}
```

It does not work :( Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is some really basic stuff about arrays and vectors that you don't quite understand. I don't know how to help with this question as the code seems incoherent.

Comment: do you want to pass one of the vectors in phi?

Comment: An array is not a table. It doesn't have "columns". It's unclear what you mean...

Comment: @user3473823 can you please explain to us what do you mean by a column instead of endless editing of the question? And vrctor is not library, this is a class in standard library

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write your program in this way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

double suma(vector<vector<double> >& H) {
    double Sum = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < H.size(); ++i) {
        // probably you need to write one more inner loop to do 
        // something with each vector.This is not very clear with your question
    }
    return Sum;
}


int main() {
   vector<vector<double> > phi(10,vector<double> (2,1.0));
    cout << suma(phi) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the sum of the first column you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//function for get the sum of all the elements of a vector H
double suma(vector<double> H) {

    double Sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < H.size(); i++) {
        Sum += H[i];
    }

    return Sum;
}

int main() {

    vector<vector<double> > phi;

    phi.resize(10, vector<double> (2,1.0));
    //if by 0th column you mean 0th vector do this:
    cout << suma(phi[0]) << endl;

    //if by 0th column you mean every 0th element of each vector do this:
    vector<double> temp;
    for(int i=0; i<phi.size(); i++)
    {
        temp.push_back(phi[i][0]);
    }
    cout << suma(temp) << endl;
}
```